# Why is this removeChild not working?

Tags: javascript, removechild

```
function usePotion(){
for (var i = 0; i < inventoryItemNumber.length; i++){
    if (inventoryItemNumber [count] == 5){

        player.hp += 5; 
        inventoryItemNumber.splice(inventoryItemNumber.indexOf(5),1);
        inventory.pop()
        document.getElementById("HP").innerHTML = "HP: " + player.hp;
        let inventoryList = document.getElementById("inventory");
        inventoryList.removeChild (inventoryList.childNodes[count]);
        return;
    }
    count++

}
return;
}
```

When I use my button to call the function everything except the removeChild command works, but if I go into console and copy/paste my 2 lines of code and execute it works fine.

There's a lot more code obviously and my count variable is a global variable = 0;

Comment: what is `count`?

Comment: So if `count` is `0`, are you sure the first node in `inventoryList` is an element and not a text node? If not, try `.children` instead of `.childNodes`.

Comment: Try `console.log(inventoryList.childNodes[count])` right before you call the removeChild.

Comment: @nnnnnn You are most definitely right. That was the problem, the first node is coming up as text. Thanks a bunch ! And thanks everyone else that helped as well!